# Minecraft Pocket Edition Commands [Private Teritory] [LAN]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

How To Private My Town To Make Blocks Unbreakable In My City From Other Players I Just Want to Protect Coty From Grief (its LAN server in MCPE)

Answer (score 1):

A feature that was recently added to Minecraft: Bedrock Edition (previously called pocket edition) is the ability to change different player's abilities in the game. To do this, you must enter the pause menu (either by pressing the back button or the pause button), and click the `Settings` button. Then scroll down on the game tab to the `Trust Player Permissions` option. Change it to `Visitor`. Now any random player that joins your world can view but not change your world.

[image]

Comment: I Want To Only City is unbrakable. its survival server. and also in my 1.1.5 version dosnt have this visitors and members feature

Comment: @Giorgi Khachidze I don't think that Minecraft PE supports that. I might be wrong though.